# Determine if a request is remote or not in Node.js with Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm learning Node. Someone told me I could use the [IPS property](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.ips) of a request to Express to determine if a request is remote (i.e. not localhost). My question is, how?

When I read the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.ips) for the IPS property it is not clear to me how I would determine if a request was made from my local development machine or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
// filter to git rid of non-local requests
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.ip.indexOf("127.0.0.1") > -1 )
    {
        console.log("Incoming request - Accepted");
        next();
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Incoming request - Rejected");
        res.send("API only accessable from the local device").status(403).end();
    }
});
```

This code will basically filter all your incoming requests and check to see if they are coming from the local host.  Keep in mind that, at least on windows, a localhost address my come in as IPv6 `::ffff:127.0.0.1` This is why we use the indexOf command.

Answer (score -1):

In you're routes:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if (req.ip != '127.0.0.1') {
    //This is not localhost
  }
}
```

Basically, you want to view the IP address of the `request` and compare it to your IP address. You can view this via `req.ip` and then decide what to do.